# How to add link to a button in html without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

button tag without using java in html

I have try using javascript but i'm curious to know is their something we can use it without javascript

Comment: Don't. Links are links. Button are buttons. They mean different things. They do different things. They have different [affordances](https://uxplanet.org/ux-design-glossary-how-to-use-affordances-in-user-interfaces-393c8e9686e4).

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

`<button><a href="yourlink">Link Button</a></button>`

but why?